# Does there exist a graph embedding that fulfils Euler's formula and is not planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a connected graph such that $r=m−n+2$, where $r$ is the number of regions, $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertices.

Does there exist a graph embedding of a nonplanar graph that satisfies $r=m-n+2$?

We define a region of a graph embedding as an area enclosed by edges and the infinite region.

Does such a graph embedding exist, and if not how can we prove that for all graph embeddings satisfying Euler's formula, the graph must be planar.

Comment: Could you clarify the notion of region for a graph in the plane whose edges intersect outside the vertices of that graph.

Comment: @kabenyuk A region is a closed area surrounded by edges, each of these areas counts as 1 region. And the portion of the plane lying outside the graph (the infinite region) counts as 1 region as well. I hope that answers your question? I'm not sure what is meant by edges intersecting outside the vertices.

Comment: No, sorry. You did not answer my question. Take a square in the plane and draw both diagonals in it. Consider a graph whose vertices are the vertices of the square and whose edges are the sides of the square and the two diagonals. How many regions does this graph have?

Comment: @kabenyuk If the graph is planar for example K4 in this case, then the number of regions will be the number of regions in the planar representation of the graph, so it would be 4 regions. So what I am trying to figure out is if a graph does not have a planar representation (i.e. it is nonplanar), can we still draw it in a way that will satisfy Euler's formula. The definition of regions changes when we talk about non-planar graphs to just be the area enclosed by the edges in ANY drawing of the graph.

Comment: It would be very good, if you supplement your question with exact definitions and give a good example to illustrate them. Otherwise, I'm afraid you are unlikely to be understood by anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with plane embeddings, there are often a ton of technical details that you need to be careful of. To make matters simpler, let me only consider *straight line embeddings* of graphs. I will allow edges to intersect, but only at interior points and not vertices (apart from edges that share a vertex, of course), and at any point other then a vertex at most two edges intersect. In this setting it seems relatively clear what a *region* is: you delete the image of the vertices and edges from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and look at the connected components.

I claim that in this setting, an embedding satisfies Euler's formula if and only if it is without crossings; that is, if it is an honest planar embedding of the graph. Indeed, if the embedding has crossings, then start putting new vertices at each crossing, so that the new vertex subdivides the two crossing edges. With each new vertex, the number of vertices increases by one, the number of edges increases by two, and the number of regions does not change. Keep doing this, and you will get the planar embedding of a graph with $n+c$ vertices and $m+2c$ edges, where $c$ is the number of crossings in the initial embedding. Euler's formula now tells you that the number of regions is $m-n + 2 + c$. Since the number of regions did not change, this is also true for the original embedding.

Since for a non-planar graph every embedding will have crossings, this shows that none of the embeddings satisfies Euler's formula.